# Swift - Use element being switched in a case

Tags: swift, switch-statement, swift4

Depending on the content of a string, I need to return one thing or another, but I have several different cases. With if else I check the content like this:

```
extension String { contains() -> Bool {...} }

if string.contains("xxx") { return 1 }
else if string.contains("yyy") { return 2 }
else if string.contains("zzz") { return 3 }
else if string.contains("aaa") { return 4 }
else { return 5 }
```

Whenever I have so many `if-else` cases (I have 8 in this case), I like using a `switch` statement, however, I have not found a way to use the string in the `case`s. I have tried:

```
switch string {
case .contains("xxx"): // Tries to check if string == .contains("xxx"), so error.
...
}
```

I have also tried:

```
switch string {
case string.contains("xxx"): // Tries to check if string == string.contains("xxx"), so error
...
}
```

Does anyone have an idea on how I could use the `switch` for this scenario? Basically calling a function on the element to be switched over.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
switch string {
case let s where s.contains("xxx"): break
case let s where s.contains("yyy"): break
default: break
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The syntax is as follows:

```
switch string {
    case let y where y.contains("xxx"): print ("Yepp")
    case let y where y.contains("aaa"): print ("Yepp")
    default: print("nope")
}
```